# An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2400 MQJE011: Socket connection attempt refused

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq

I wrote a program to put messages into MQ . It works fine when I don't have SSL configuration in place. If I configure SSL in QueueManager and Channel, always getting An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2400
MQJE011: Socket connection attempt refused. Tried with different cipher suite
Please advise how to resolve it.

SSL properties :

```
com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"; 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "D:/keystore/testKS.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "12345678");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "D:/keystore/testKS.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "12345678");
```

Comment: SSL proeprties :   com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"; 
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "D:/keystore/testKS.jks");
               System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "12345678");
               System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "D:/keystore/testKS.jks"); 
               System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "12345678");

Comment: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher is supported only from MQ v8.0.0.3. Are you at that level?

Comment: yeah I am using MQ 8

Answer (score 6):

**This answer specific to Java code .**

Java JREs, including Oracle/Sun and IBM's have Import Limits on Cryptographic Algorithms enabled. This limits the maximum key sizes and also some algorithms.

When trying to use a AES 256 cipher, such as **ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384** or **TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256** , you need to ensure JRE supports this cipher. In most cases, when the stronger cipher algorithms are needed, such as AES 256 ciphers, the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files must be obtained and installed in the JDK/JRE.

This is mentioned in the JDK/JRE documentation: For Oracle 1.7:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html

For IBM JRE: ** Cipher suites that use AES_256 require installation of the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.71.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/ciphersuites.html?lang=en

This is similar to the issue noted with IBM MQ Explorer in :

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/187285/why-is-a-mqrc-ssl-initialization-error-displayed-w.html

Please updated this JAR File run with MSPKI and Cipher value “TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA”

New policy jar which will support all the algorithms, you need to update jars into your **C:\java-8\jdk1_8_0\jre\lib\security**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html

Answer (score 4):

The MQRC return code you were given is a very strong hint. Your first act to diagnose any problem should be to look up the MQRC number. You can do this quickly at a command prompt on any machine with MQ installed by typing

```
mqrc 2400
```

You can also look it up in Knowledge Center.

[MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE (2400)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q044280_.htm)

If you read the more detailed information at the above link that fully describes the reason code, you will see that it means the JSSE does not support that cipher.

@Shashi has given you the answer in the comment above that the cipher you are using was very recently introduced.

Comment: thanks , was able to resolve it by getting the java cipher's supported and matching it with MQ .

Answer (score 2):

In my case, setting the following property to client JVM helped:

```
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false
```

Here is official document is explaining it - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q113210_.htm#q113210___mappings